# R iterate to read csv files

Tags: r, csv

```
pollutantmean <- function(id){
    n <- length(id)
    for (i in 1 : n){
        pol <- read.csv('id[i].csv')
    }
}
pollutantmean(150:160)
```

The filenames of csv are like 001.csv, 002.csv, 100.csv etc
001, 002 and 100, these are id, and each csv has a column of id whose content is 1 if the filename is 001.

When I run this code, the console remind me this is no such file id[i].csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is line 4 and it should be replaced by

```
pol <- read.csv(paste0(id[i], ".csv"))
```

If `id[i]` is within quotes (either simple or double), it's understood litterally by `read.csv`, eg the function is looking for something named `id[i].csv` and which explains your error message.

**But** with such function, `pol` will be overwritten anyway at every step anyway.

If you really want to wrapup these lines into a function you need to return a list:

```
pollutantmean <- function(id){
    res <- vector("list", length(id))
    for (i in 1:n){
        res[[i]] <- read.csv(paste0(id[i], ".csv"))
    }
}
```

But a loop here would not be very elegant here, so we can simply:

```
pollutantmean <- function(id){
    lapply(id, function(i) read.csv(paste0(i, ".csv"))
}
```

Or even (no function option) this should work:

```
lapply(id, function(i) read.csv(paste0(i, ".csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need a loop. And second, you need to think about how to represent ids.

```
ids <- sprintf("%03i", 1:999) # 0's are padded at the beginning
filenames <- paste0(ids, ".csv")
results <- lapply(filenames, read.csv) # you get a list of data frames
```

Alternatively you can read in all csv files in a certain folder using, say:

```
results <- lapply(dir(pattern="\\.csv$"), read.csv)
```

The "\.csv$" stuff means that ".csv" has to be at the end of the filename. (see ?regexpr for technicalities)

... and a function that takes a number and gives you back a data frame would look like this:

```
read.this <- function(i) read.csv(sprintf("%003i.csv",i))
```

... And now you can lapply it to your desired range:

```
lapply(101:150, read.this)
```